# Mongoose random and mix response from populated model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Need some help with big social network that I am building using Node js and Mongoose for my MongoDB.

My idea is to mix response from model, to show one post from category that user is following, then to show post from another category that user is also following, then to show one from group(*private category*). Similarly 3 + 1 (3 category + 1 group) post, but user can follow many categories, and have many groups.

**Is there something I can use to get posts from RANDOM categories + groups? 
I am trying here not to invent the wheel by writing random logic with `Math`**

So this is my simplified Schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    groups: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'}],
    followingCategories: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}]
});

var postSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}
});

var categorySchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    group: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'},
    posts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]
});

var groupSchema = new Schema({
    users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    categories: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'category'}]
});
```

And it must be usable through User model like:

```
User.findById(..., function(err, user){
    //logic that gets user posts from random categories and groups
});
```

Keeping in mind following:

1. It must be fast (*expecting **millions post***)
2. It uses `limit(10)` and `skip(int)` for API lazy load
3. Categories and group are random, but posts are in order `{created_at: desc}`
4. User can follow many `categories` and can be in many `groups`.

Comment: please clarify, what is your question?

Comment: @DianaHolland Advanced random function for multiple relation holders is the thing he is looking for if, I understood well

Comment: @MladenJanjetovic Why did you remove some code from OP in your first edit? The code might have been relevant for some other people...

Comment: @ThomasBormans No, it won't. It is just random c/p of Math random function found online, and it is misleading

Comment: I think that question here is actually "How can I get all posts from groups I follow, followed categories, and followed users?"

Answer (score 0):

If I fully understood your question, which is a bit unclear, you're looking for aggregation and [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) operator. It randomly selects documents form collection.

Comment: Can your give me example how will your do it with $sample, because i don't have idea... Like @MladenJanjetovic say: I think that question here is actually "How can I get all posts from groups I follow, followed categories, and followed users?"

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a random function

```
QuoteSchema.statics.random = function(callback) {
  this.count(function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    this.findOne()
   .skip(rand)
   .exec(callback);
  }
  .bind(this));
};
```

Instead of using `findbyId` use `findOne`.